# suexec and docroot problem

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-fastcgi, suexec

I've got a problem with running a FastCgiServer under apache2. When I define a virtual host with a static fcgi server configured, I get an error from suexec:

```
command not in docroot (/var/www-blah/dispatcher.fcgi)
```

Which is correct, because docroot is `/var/www`. But when I use a dynamic fastcgi generated by `AddHandler` magic, I'm also using `suexec` and the same problem doesn't occur - even though the script lives in `/home/.../public_html/dispatcher.fcgi`.

What causes `suexec` to run correctly there? And how can I replicate that behaviour on the virtual host?

**Update:** Actually, I moved my stuff from `/var/www-blah` to `/var/www/blah`, so it's under docroot and it works. I guess suexec has some public_html detection.

What still doesn't work though is dynamic fastcgi with suexec under `/var/www/...`. Even though the script is owned by the correct user, suexec doesn't show any errors and doesn't seem to run (script works as www-data)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

suexec only executes programs within an apache document root. See [the suexec security model](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/suexec.html#model), particularly point 13.